# what's the difference between by passing a symbol and string in where clause with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models User and Book. User have username and email field, Book have author and title field. When I am using joins to get the users based on associated data with conditions passed in where clause, I am getting different results

1. When I run this

   ```
   User.joins(:books).where('author = ? ','xxxx')
   ```

Mysql query generated is :

```
 "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `books` ON `books`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE (author = 'xxxxx' )"
```

gives me the user whose book include xxxx author whereas

2. When I run this

   ```
   User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')
   ```

Mysql query generated is:

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `books` ON `books`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`author` = 'xxxx'">
```

gives Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.author' in 'where clause':

```
 SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `books` ON `books`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`author` = 'xxxx'
```

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.author' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `book` ON `book`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`author` = 'Dan Brown'

**My question :** is when I am passing a string encapsulated field and value in where clause it gives me result but when I pass a symbol in where clause it gives me mysql unknown column error. So how does ruby interpreter know from where to fetch data in symbol passing and string passing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we join the tables especially in rails the rails has a power to take the aliasing of the joined tables.

Your query,
     `User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')` searches for the author field in the **user table**

`User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')` **always takes the field of first table** and

`User.joins(:books).where('author = ? ','xxxx')` **searches in both the tables**

For example, `User.joins(:books).where('id = ? ','xxxx')`, try this query.

**In the above You will get an error because `id` field is present in both the tables and it gets confused**

but,

`User.joins(:books).where(id: 'xxxx')` **works because it searches only in the users table.**

so, you can use, **refer author through books** `books: {author: 'xxxx'}`

```
User.joins(:books).where(books: {author: 'xxxx'})   // your required query
```

or

```
User.joins(:books).where('author = ? ','xxxx')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sravan. But my question is how does rails decide when passing string to search for author in books table whereas when passing symbol it decides to search in users table

Answer (score -1):

`User.joins(:books).where('author = ? ','xxxx')` is free from sql injection but `User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')` is not .

It is good to use `User.joins(:books).where('author = ? ','xxxx')` as it is easier to write more complex where clause.

When you are writing `User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')` rails interpreter will try to interpret as **users.author = 'xxxx'**

You can check the [link](http://rails-sqli.org/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sabyasachi. But my question is how does rails decide when passing string to search for author in books table whereas when passing symbol it decides to search in users table

Comment: could you elaborate on how exactly `.where(author: 'xxx')` is vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: how it is not free from sql injection User.joins(:books).where(author: 'xxxx')?